# (Novel?) story identification - a child gets control over the colors of sunrise and makes a mess of it

Tags: story-identification

We read a chapter from this in grade school, but never the whole novel (or novella or something).  Here is all I can remember:

- There was a character who could prop himself up in mid air.  He slept this way one night
- I am pretty sure there was a character named "Alex"
- Alex may have been the person who could prop himself up in mid air
- The chapter we read had an apparently normal character who gained control over the colors of the sunrise
- They didn't know what they were doing, so they accidentally made the sunrise on a particular morning weirdly colorful and hoped that no one would notice because it was so early in the morning
- I am also pretty sure that the story is in first person narration, and that the character who screwed up the colors was the narrator

Comment: This sounds a lot like parts of *The Phantom Tollbooth*.

Comment: I think you're right! I just took a look at its wikipedia article and it seems almost exactly to match.  Add it as an answer and I'll accept when I'm allowed to

Comment: @RLH Just make sure you don’t jump to the Island of Conclusions. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is *[The Phantom Tollbooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_Tollbooth)* by Norton Juster.

> The story follows a bored young boy named Milo who unexpectedly receives a magic tollbooth that transports him to the once prosperous, but now troubled, Kingdom of Wisdom. Along with a dog named Tock and the Humbug, Milo goes on a quest to the Castle in the Air seeking the kingdom's two exiled princesses, named Rhyme and Reason. As Milo learns valuable lessons, he finds a love of learning in a story full of puns and wordplay, such as exploring the literal meanings of idioms.

The boy floating in midair is "Alec Bings, a little boy suspended in the air who sees through things and who will grow down until he reaches the ground." The incident with the sunrise is Milo subbing in for "Chroma the Great, a conductor whose orchestra creates the colors of the world."

> “Won’t Chroma be surprised?” he thought, signaling the musicians to stop. “I’ll wake him now.”
>
> But, instead of stopping, they continued to play even louder than before, until each color became more brilliant than he thought possible. Milo shielded his eyes with one hand and waved the other desperately, but the colors continued to grow brighter and brighter and brighter, until an even more curious thing began to happen.
>
> As Milo frantically conducted, the sky changed slowly from blue to tan and then to a rich magenta red. Flurries of light-green snow began to fall, and the leaves on the trees and bushes turned a vivid orange.
> As Milo frantically conducted, the sky changed slowly from blue to tan and then to a rich magenta red. Flurries of light-green snow began to fall, and the leaves on the trees and bushes turned a vivid orange.
>
> All the flowers suddenly appeared black, the gray rocks became a lovely soft chartreuse, and even peacefully sleeping Tock changed from brown to a magnificent ultramarine. Nothing was the color it should have been, and yet, the more he tried to straighten things out, the worse they became.
>
> “I wish I hadn’t started,” he thought unhappily as a pale-blue blackbird flew by. “There doesn’t seem to be any way to stop them.”
>
> He tried very hard to do everything just the way Chroma had done, but nothing worked. The musicians played on, faster and faster, and the purple sun raced quickly across the sky. In less than a minute it had set once more in the west and then, without any pause, risen again in the east. The sky was now quite yellow and the grass a charming shade of lavender. Seven times the sun rose and almost as quickly disappeared as the colors kept changing. In just a few minutes a whole week had gone by.
>
> At last the exhausted Milo, afraid to call for help and on the verge of tears, dropped his hands to his sides. The orchestra stopped. The colors disappeared, and once again it was night. The time was 5:27 A.M.
>
> “Wake up, everybody! Time for the sunrise!” he shouted with relief, and quickly jumped from the music stand.

Comment: Serving as a placeholder until RLH writes his own answer.

Comment: Go ahead and take it -- I'm not going to get to writing a proper answer.

Comment: Accepted given the discussion in the comments.  Thanks!